# model creation/loading in plumber endpoint

Tags: r, plumber

I follow this [great post](https://medium.com/tmobile-tech/using-docker-to-deploy-an-r-plumber-api-863ccf91516d) and this [repo](https://github.com/nolis-llc/r-api-tutorial). Here the rest endpoint looks like this:

```
# build the model
source("make_model.R")

#* @get /predict_petal_length
get_predict_length <- function(petal_width){
  
  # convert the input to a number
  petal_width <- as.numeric(petal_width)
  
  #create the prediction data frame
  prediction_data <- data.frame(Petal.Width=petal_width)
  
  # create the prediction
  predict(model,prediction_data)
}
```

and make_model.R like this:

```
dataset <- iris

# create the model
model <- lm(Petal.Length ~ Petal.Width, data = dataset)
```

All straightforward and it works fine. Just curious would each GET request initiate the execution of make_model.R or does this work a bit like a Singleton design pattern? In other words, would make_model.R only be executed once? Thanks.

Comment: `make_model.R` is only executed once, and the prediction is made separately for each request.

Comment: @mhovd thanks good to know. so I could also load a model into memory from within the docker image? Thanks - sorry just did my first docker plumber endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To continue on my comment, `source"(make_model.R")` will only be run once.
The results will be available to all requests that are made. This means that you can load datasets or models once, and these will be shared with the environments for your requests.

From [the documentation](https://www.rplumber.io/articles/execution-model.html):

> By default, when you create a new Plumber router (which happens
> implicitly when you call plumb() on a file), a new environment is
> created especially for this router. It is in this environment that all
> expressions will be evaluated and all endpoints invoked.